# Converting an INT column to an ENUM column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following INT column in my MySQL table with two records:

[image]

I have tried to change the datatype to ENUM with following:

```
`BetalingsStatus` ENUM ('BestillingRegistreret','FakturaSendt','Betalt') NOT NULL,
```

But my existing data goes missing. How do I convert my existing INT values to ENUM ?.

Comment: Add new column, update values from old to new, remove old column, rename new column.

Comment: Also consider not using `enum` [here's some good reasons why](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/)

Answer (score 3):

create the new column:

```
ALTER TABLE XXX ADD `BetalingsStatus_Tmp` ENUM('BestillingRegistreret','FakturaSendt','Betalt') NOT NULL DEFAULT '' AFTER BetalingsStatus;
```

Update the data:

```
UPDATE XXXX SET BetalingsStatus_Tmp = CASE BetalingsStatus 
WHEN 0 THEN 'BestillingRegistreret'
WHEN 1 THEN 'FakturaSendt'
WHEN 2 THEN 'Betalt'
END
```

Delete old column:

```
ALTER TABLE XXX DROP BetalingsStatus;
```

Rename tmp column:

```
ALTER TABLE XXX CHANGE BetalingsStatus_Tmp BetalingsStatus ENUM('BestillingRegistreret','FakturaSendt','Betalt') NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is to change file type **INT** to **ENUM**.

Here is one of the examples to fix it. First, you must use 'ALTER TABLE', since, you are updating **inside** a table, not changing the table itself.

Here is an example for that, try this.

`ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY column_name ENUM('sample1', 'sample2');`

I hope it helps.

Comment: Or you can use this ```ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY column_name ENUM('sample1', 'sample2') NOT NULL;```